# Input validation in WinUI3 Community Toolkit DataGrid with c#

Tags: c#, winui-3, windows-community-toolkit

I have a WinUI3 c# app that uses DataGrid from Windows Community Toolkit.

DataGrid is populated with Observable Collection, that consists of objects (which are basically rows from database, where property = column)

Users can edit this datatable. And for that of course I want to make sure that the input is correct. So that they can't enter letters in the cell, where there are should only be numbers, etc.

According to [Windows Community Toolkit Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid_guidance/editing_inputvalidation) it should be done through INotifyDataErrorInfo in your DataModel or ViewModel. But it feels like it is too complex and I just need simple check.

So far, I could only come up with a plan, where I give columns in datagrid a certain tag, let's say "string", "int", "date". And then on "CellEditEdning" event check which tag the column has and based on that tag check the input, but I am not sure if that is a good idea and how to implement this.

So, I wanted to ask if there is any easier method to do it or should I do it all with  INotifyDataErrorInfo, even if it is a simple check.

Answer (score 0):

[`INotifyDataErrorInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo?view=net-7.0) is just the mechanism to tell the UI that there are errors in your data.

It doesn't matter whether the validation rules are complex or simple, you still need a way to communicate that there are errors.

Sure you could use a different strategy, but that would probably be more work than you think because you'll likely have to implement some custom UI and a notification system. Whereas, as you pointed out from the documentation, `DataGrid` already supports validation so half of the problem is already solved. Basically, the UI part (like display red cells) is already done. All you have to do is adjust your C# to have your objects implement `INotifyDataErrorInfo`.

**I recommend that you implement `INotifyDataErrorInfo` instead of doing a custom implementation. It's likely the simplest solution to your problem.**

If you don't want to implement `INotifyDataErrorInfo` yourself, you could also use existing implementations that do it for you. You'll just have to learn how to set them up.
Here's an example of a MVVM framework that does implement `INotifyDataErrorInfo` and that I used: https://github.com/nventive/Chinook.DynamicMvvm#chinookdynamicmvvm